# Class 'kotlin.collections.ArraysKt__ArraysJVMKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin using ./gradlew assembleRelease in VS code

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to release my react native app using `./gradlew assembleRelease` in the directory `android`, but I got the following error: `The class is loaded from /home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-bin/1w5dpkrfk8irigvoxmyhowfim/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/io/FilesKt__UtilsKt.class e: /home/enzo/Desktop/Projetos/React Native/caraCoroa/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/tasks/GenerateCodegenSchemaTask.kt: (67, 42): Class 'kotlin.collections.ArraysKt__ArraysJVMKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.` I'm using Visual Studio Code for Linux.

Here's some code I tried with no success:

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.0"
}
```